# Is there a way to sum only integer from rows and then sum strings without integer

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table

```
------------------------------------------
     id     |       Machines               
------------------------------------------
     1.     |       1 Truck              
------------------------------------------ 
     2.     |       1 Bobcat             
------------------------------------------
     3.     |       2 Platform          
------------------------------------------   
     4.     |       Telehender            
------------------------------------------
     5.     |       Teodolit, 3 Platform 
------------------------------------------
     6.     |       2 Tractor             
------------------------------------------
     7.     |         NULL             
------------------------------------------ 
  Result:   |         11                 
------------------------------------------
```

I want to sum firstly integers (1+1+2+3+2), then SUM Count of values without Integer (Telehender and Teodolit = 2) and skip NULL values..
The result of this table need to be 11.

I am using this query

```
 SELECT Sum((Char_length(machines) - Char_length(Replace(machines, ',','')) + 1)) AS ukupno
FROM   izvestaji
WHERE  projekatid='8'
AND    datum='2019-10-03'
```

But I get the Result = 9.

Is there a way to make that query?

Comment: Instead of trying to solve this, I would re-think the design of the database. This is poorly designed. One field should contain only 1 information. Do never serialize datas in DB. Consider using [normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Comment: I wonder how you could distinguish a machine product number from a quantity eg 3 bmw318i

Comment: Is there any way to do this with PHP?

Comment: try to change design of your database to fix easily and find more solution to solve that you want to query. `Think if this design will be faster or easier to manipulate`:D

Answer (score 1):

Bad bad database design... :/
However , here it it a solution in which i suppose you have no more than 3 elements
 into machines field

```
SELECT 
        sum(case
                when length(machines)-length(replace(machines,',','')) = 0
                then if( CAST(machines AS UNSIGNED) = 0, 1, cast(machines as unsigned))

                when length(machines)-length(replace(machines,',','')) = 1
                  then ( if( CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(machines, ',', 1) AS UNSIGNED) = 0, 1, cast(SUBSTRING_INDEX(machines, ',', 1) as unsigned))) +  
                       (if( CAST(replace(machines , concat(SUBSTRING_INDEX(machines, ',', 1),','),'') AS UNSIGNED) = 0, 1, cast(replace(machines , concat(SUBSTRING_INDEX(machines, ',', 1),','),'') as unsigned)))

                when length(machines)-length(replace(machines,',','')) = 2
                  then ( if( CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(machines, ',', 1) AS UNSIGNED) = 0, 1, cast(SUBSTRING_INDEX(machines, ',', 1) as unsigned))) +  
                       (if( CAST(replace(machines , concat(SUBSTRING_INDEX(machines, ',', 1),','),'') AS UNSIGNED) = 0, 1, cast(replace(machines , concat(SUBSTRING_INDEX(machines, ',', 1),','),'') as unsigned))) +
                       (if( CAST(replace(machines , concat(SUBSTRING_INDEX(machines, ',', 2),','),'') AS UNSIGNED) = 0, 1, cast(replace(machines , concat(SUBSTRING_INDEX(machines, ',', 2),','),'') as unsigned)))


             end) AS ukupno
FROM   izvestaji
#WHERE  projekatid='8'
#AND    datum='2019-10-03'
```

you can obtain other cases from 2 to M including cases like this

```
when length(machines)-length(replace(machines,',','')) = M
                      then ( if( CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(machines, ',', 1) AS UNSIGNED) = 0, 1, cast(SUBSTRING_INDEX(machines, ',', 1) as unsigned))) +  
                           (if( CAST(replace(machines , concat(SUBSTRING_INDEX(machines, ',', 1),','),'') AS UNSIGNED) = 0, 1, cast(replace(machines , concat(SUBSTRING_INDEX(machines, ',', 1),','),'') as unsigned))) +
                           (if( CAST(replace(machines , concat(SUBSTRING_INDEX(machines, ',', 2),','),'') AS UNSIGNED) = 0, 1, cast(replace(machines , concat(SUBSTRING_INDEX(machines, ',', 2),','),'') as unsigned))) +

...

(if( CAST(replace(machines , concat(SUBSTRING_INDEX(machines, ',', j),','),'') AS UNSIGNED) = 0, 1, cast(replace(machines , concat(SUBSTRING_INDEX(machines, ',', j),','),'') as unsigned))) +


...

(if( CAST(replace(machines , concat(SUBSTRING_INDEX(machines, ',', M),','),'') AS UNSIGNED) = 0, 1, cast(replace(machines , concat(SUBSTRING_INDEX(machines, ',', M),','),'') as unsigned)))
```

if you see case 1 or case 2 i think you can understand it.

Comment: of course i assumed the same condition for the sum so i edited in order to sum up all over the table...

Comment: This works perfectly, but is there a way to count it there is more than 2 elements into machines field? This is an app where users enters data, so I don't know how much machines they will enter in one field.

Comment: Actually this is working until 3 elements (the number tested in the query it's related to the commas). This is just a workaround but of course you can extend it to more number of elements nut i cannot give you a general solution. What you can do maybe it's to check and limit the data entered by the user. In your case for doing this calculation in general you need maybe a recursively function wich can give you the result but i think it would be just a trick , consider a database design. If you want to exted this query to more cases just copy paste the case before . I'll edit the answer .

Comment: When I copy and paste, I get this error Unknown column 'M' in 'field list'.

Answer (score 1):

You can use combinations of `sign()`, `abs()`, `substr()`, `instr()` and `length()` functions, and can filter the integer values by `string + 0` formula :

```
select sum( int_value_1 + int_value_2 ) +
       sum( case when int_value_1 = 0 or int_value_2 = 0  then 
          sign( length(before_comma) ) + abs( sign( after_comma+0 ) - 1 )  
       end) as total
  from
(
select substr( Machines, 1, instr(Machines,',') - 1 ) + 0 as int_value_1,
       substr( Machines, instr(Machines,',')+1, length(Machines) ) as int_value_2,
       substr( Machines, 1, instr(Machines,',') - 1 ) as before_comma,
       substr( Machines, instr(Machines,',')+1, length(Machines) ) as after_comma
  from izvestaji
) i;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=01361d5ef7b8e247725ba5700f1bb204)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks, this works fine... but sometime It makes a mistake when counting. Check this example.
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=6c9aee5b4ba97b8a45fe807026e215f3

Comment: Now it works fine... but what If I have more then 2 elements in the field? 
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=c7f31d54d6f0f1b0e83ea1aeef0a6b6b
Is there solution for that?

Comment: going harder :) maybe within the scope of another question @AleksandarMilosevic